# No Internet Access in VMWare VM and specific VLAN

Tags: virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere, vlan, vswitch

I have a VM that was in a VLAN (3) and has a static IP address. Yesterday i could not connect via rdp and found out that it lost its connection. Things I tried first:

- Disable / Enable Network Adapter
- Change VM Adapter Typ
- Reboot the Machine

But all of this have not solved the problem. So I tried to move the VM in another VLAN (16). Then RDP Connection worked and i was in the domain. When I changed the Proxy settings to "Automatically detect proxy settings" I also was able to connect to the internet.

But when I switch back to the VLAN (3) it doesnt recognize the Domain and the Network (undefined network)

Does anybody has a clue what could be the error?

Comment: You're going to have to provide a LOT more information than you have

Comment: Check the port where the host is connected whether VLAN 3 is passed.

Comment: Check with physical machine with VLAN 3 IP.

Comment: You haven't given us nearly enough information. For starters, when you say you moved the VM to another VLAN, how did you do that exactly? Are you using External Switch Tagging, Virtual Switch Tagging, or Virtual Guest Tagging?